# Given correlation coefficient, how do you compute explained variance and then confidence interval?

Tags: regression, correlation

I am interested in estimating my calories burned at the gym given my heart rate. I found this paper from 2005 which used a 5-variable (4 if VO2 max is excluded) model to estimate calories expended: http://www.braydenwm.com/cal_vs_hr_ref_paper.pdf

The paper says that the 4-variable model (does not use VO2 max) had a correlation coefficient of 0.857. They say it follows that this model accounts for 73.4% of the variance in calories burned.

1) Given a correlation coefficient, how can one compute the accounted-for variance?

2) Given a correlation coefficient, how can I find a 95% confidence interval for the value the model predicts for calories I burn during a session at the gym?

3) If calculating a confidence interval is not possible, how else might I get some sense of the <s>"spread"</s> "confidence" of predictions given by this model using the model performance metrics given in the paper?

I understand how one computes variance given a model and a set of measurements. But translating from metric to metric is beyond me.

Edit: "Spread" was probably the wrong word. I realize any prediction returned by a multiple linear regression model will lie on a hyperplane. What I'm looking for is some sense of how far off the model could be.

Edit: I found this link (https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/274/) that shows how to compute a prediction interval for simple linear regression and this link (https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/315/) that shows how to compute a prediction interval for multiple linear regression. They both require the MSE, which is not reported in the paper.

Edit: Another useful link on the difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals: https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall13/sta101/slides/unit7lec3H.pdf

Edit: Confidence intervals vs prediction intervals? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_estimation

Comment: $0.857^2 =  0.7344 = r^2$ (often written $R^2$ in computer output). In regression the square of the correlation $r$ is often said to represent the proportion of the variability in the predicted variable $Y$ that is 'explained' by regression on $x.$ A relevant equation from simple linear regression is $S_{Y|x}^2 = \frac{n-1}{n-2}S_Y^2(1-r^2).$